# PHP - Static property in extended/child class

Tags: php, inheritance, static, extends

If I have a base abstract class like so:

```
<?php
abstract class Record {
    static $table;

    public function getRows () {
        return getRowsFromTable(static::$table);
    }
}
?>
```

And I want to extend this class like so:

```
<?php
class User extends Record {
    static $table = 'users';

    private $name;
?>
```

Then if I call:

```
<?php
$user = new User;
$user->getRows();
?>
```

Internally, `getRows()` calls and returns `getRowsFromTable('users')`.

But if I were to create another class that also extends `Record`:

```
<?php
class House extends Record {
    static $table = 'houses';

    private $address;
?>
```

Then that `static $table = 'houses';` declaration overrides the `Record::$table` and, consequently, breaks the `User` class.

What's happening is, the declaration `static $table = 'houses';` bubbles up to the parent class, so now `Record::$table = 'houses';`. Since `House` was declared after `User`, the next time I call `$user->getRows()`, internally, `User` references parent `Record` and ultimately calls `getRowsFromTable('houses')` instead of `getRowsFromTable('users')`.

I'm using late static binding so as to get the property from the extended class; but since `User` and `House` extend the same parent class, they both end up with the same property value although they override it with different values.

If I were to duplicate the `Record` class by creating a class `Record2` and having `House` extend `Record2`, I wouldn't have this problem -- but that wouldn't really help.

Is this the wrong setup? Should I not be using static variables in this context? What should I put in their place, if so? I know that `$table` doesn't necessarily have to be static, but there are other properties that may need to be static.

Comment: `parent::`? Perhaps you should try th at

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm with you on 'breaks the User class' - can you explain your issue with it a little further?

Comment: Does it work with `self::` instead of `static::`?

Comment: Neither `parent` nor `self` would work, `parent` would trigger an error (as there is no parent in the `Record` class scope), and `self` would always return `null` (as it would access `$table` in the `Record` class scope). His example code requires [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), so he must use `static`. @jon_darkstar @GeorgeMarques

Comment: @ndm - I totally agree you: there's no `parent` above Record, and `self` would remain ever-null regardless of what any child class does. What that all doesn't explain, and what I'm still missing, is the reason for OP being discontent. @M Miller: how does this all differ from your expected/desired behavior? What is it that you believe breaks the `User` class?

Comment: @jon_darkstar oops, actually I wanted to mention Daryl Gill instead of you. I'm with you, this question needs more info.

Comment: @ndm, @jon_darkstar: I added some to clarify the issue by 3 paragraphs following "breaks the `User` class". Thanks for your help, and sorry if I was unclear!

Comment: Works fine for me. Either you are facing a bug (what's your exact PHP Version?), or there's some other code affecting your logic. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y71-w3a | http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/y71-w3a

Comment: You're right. My logic is actually more complex, so the simple example I made doesn't really apply. I'm going to have to compose a completely different question. My bad....

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't use a static string for this purpose.

How about something like this...

```
abstract class Record {
    /**
     * @return table name as string
     */
    abstract protected function getTable();

    public function getRows () {
        return getRowsFromTable($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

Then, your concrete implementations would have to implement `getTable`, eg

```
class User extends Record {
    protected function getTable() {
        return 'users';
    }
}
```